# Changing the color of the first letter of some text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following string: *"*Username"*.

Is there a way to change the color of the asterik while keeping the  *"Username"* part as is?

Comment: First letter or first word ? That's not clear.

Comment: so the text starts with '(some text)' ?

Comment: Don't the many links at the right answer your question ?

Comment: @ShuklaJayシ That's a __horrible__ suggestion. jQuery would offer no advantage here and wound needlessly include thousands of lines of unneeded code. Please research the topic further before making such bad suggestions to users.

Comment: Did you write `(asterisk)` here because of a conflict with Markdown *(italics text)* or is the `(asterisk)` actually written in your code? *(Tip: `\*` will write \* or you can wrap code in backticks \`like so\`.)*

Comment: @PetrR. I'm sure he meant to write an actual asterisk symbol but had trouble escaping it. Fixed the question according to the title.

Comment: well i wanted to write the character but there was some problem going on that wouldnt let me, so i had to use it as a word

Comment: sorry, should have spotted that you meant literal asterisk - updated my answer.

Comment: It looks like a li element would have been better suited.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to write an answer using proper DOM methods to do that, it's not the shortest but I don't use regular expressions or string concatenation and manipulation.

The algorithm is quite simple.

- You have to select all the elements that contain the text you want to highlight.
- Create a highlighted asterisk.
- Replace the old content with the new one where the first character is an asterisk.

Here's the JavaScript part.

```
// Create the span containing the highlighted asterisk
var asterisk = document.createElement('span');
asterisk.className = 'highlight';
asterisk.appendChild(document.createTextNode('*'));


/*
 * users is a NodeList in my case.
 * Walk the users (teehee) and check if the first characer is an asterisk
 */
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
    var user = users[i];
    var text = user.textContent;

    if (text.charAt(0) == '*') {
        user.removeChild(user.firstChild);
        user.appendChild(asterisk);
        user.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.slice(1)));
    }
}
```

<sup>*Note: I'm aware of the implications of using* `.textContent`*, if you want to support IE<9 please shim it.*</sup>

You'll also need a CSS class that defines how a highlighted asterisk span will look like.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mainerror/mhrGh/) you can play around with.

Comment: +1. As for the shim, it's simply `var text = user.textContent || user.innerText;`.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to wrap it in a containing element, a really basic example might be:

```
var str = '*Username';
str = str.replace(/^\*(.*)/, '<span style="color:red">*</span>$1');
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UYb2D/3/)

Comment: assumes containing element for whole body of text is set with color:white already - if that wasn't obvious.

Comment: works, i would have liked to say thanks but apparently it says here to avoid saying "thanks" :p , i don't get it though

Comment: @DecisiveReason It's a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), `/^\*(.*)/` reads as: match a literal asterisk at the start of the string and capture everything after it.  So the replacement value is essentially replacing the entire string with a new string - only the `$1` at the end of it denotes a place-holder for the first (and only) "capture group" in the regex (the stuff between the brackets), in our case the *Username*.

Answer (score 1):

## The JavaScript way

You can use the **[`.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)** and **[`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)** methods to recolor the first character *(no matter what the first character is nor how many asterisks are there)*:

```
var oldString = document.getElementById('element').innerHTML;
var newString = "<span style='color:red'>"
    + oldString.charAt(0)
    + "</span>"
    + "<span style='color:white'>"
    + oldString.slice(1)
    + "</span>";
document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = newString;
```

### [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jGFmH/)

---

## The CSS-only way

If you don't want to use JavaScript or the JavaScript way seems to be long to you, there is no need for JavaScript at all. However, this method requires that the asterisk (`*`) is not written in the HTML markup. The following code will add a red asterisk before everything with `class='required'`

```
.required:before
{
    color: red;
    content: "* ";
}
```

### [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jGFmH/2)

Comment: kinda big isn't it?? isn't there a solution that is less bigger? i apolagize for my ungratefulness

Comment: @DecisiveReason - I added a CSS only way for you: 0 bytes of JavaScript.

Comment: actually i wanted to have text like "Username" but after clicking . i wanted it to be changed to "(asterik)Username" and wanted "(asterik)" to be red , i thought it would be easier with javascript , but if you still have a better solution i'll be grateful :)