# First letter not working if -webkit-box display property is set

Tags: css, webkit

I want to display the first letter in red color but I've noticed when I using `display: -webkit-box` the `first-letter` property may not works anymore.

**Expected behavior :**
Apply style to first-letter (in CSS only) and keep the `display` property which is used to active `-webkit-line-clamp` property (or find a CSS alternative to display the only two first lines as now without use the `line-clamp` and `display` properties which will permit to do works the `first-letter` property).

```css
h2 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

    width: 75px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

h2::first-letter {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>This is a pretty simple test</h2>
```

Comment: `display: -webkit-box;` is obsolete.

Comment: related for workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62855106/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be accurate, `::first-letter` only works for:

- `display: block;`
- `display: inline-block;`
- `display: flow-root;`

So if you want a result that fit you, you should use js [Color JS based on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418031/changing-the-color-of-the-first-letter-of-some-text-in-javascript)

### DEMO:

```js
(function() {
    // Let's get all user names, you might have another structure
    var users = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
    
    // Create the span containing the highlighted asterisk
    var asterisk = document.createElement('span');
    asterisk.className = 'highlight';
    
    // Walk the users (teehee) and check if the first characer is an asterisk
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
      var user = users[i];
      var text = user.textContent;
      var firstLetter = text[0];
      asterisk.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstLetter));
      user.removeChild(user.firstChild);
      user.appendChild(asterisk);
      user.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.slice(1)));
    }
})();
```

```css
h2 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  width: 75px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

/*h2::first-letter {
  color: red;
}*/

.highlight {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<h2>This is a pretty simple test</h2>
```